# Footer width on mobile phone

Tags: html, css, wordpress, responsive-design

I am building a website in wordpress from a theme. The website should be responsive, but there is one problem when I go there on my mobile phone. The footer is just too wide and the rest of the content is pushed to left and makes just a thin stripe.

Here is the website: [WEBSITE URL](http://svycarsky-dum.geneweb.cz/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a div in your footer tag that has an inline style with a width of 960px. Look at the div inside of the div with the class `site-info`.

Current div HTML:

```
<div class="site-info">
    <div style="width:960px; margin:0 auto;">
        <p style="float:left;">© Copyright 2015 Hotel Švýcarský Dům</p>
        <div style="float:right;">Naleznete nás na sociálních sítích:
            <a style="display: block; float:right; margin:-4px 0 0 5px;" href=""><img src="/wp-content/themes/adamos/images/gplus.png"></a>
            <a style="display: block; float:right; margin:-4px 5px 0 5px;" href=""><img src="/wp-content/themes/adamos/images/facebook.png"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Change it to this:

```
<div class="site-info">
    <div style="margin:0 auto;">
        <p style="float:left;">© Copyright 2015 Hotel Švýcarský Dům</p>
        <div style="float:right;">Naleznete nás na sociálních sítích:
            <a style="display: block; float:right; margin:-4px 0 0 5px;" href=""><img src="/wp-content/themes/adamos/images/gplus.png"></a>
            <a style="display: block; float:right; margin:-4px 5px 0 5px;" href=""><img src="/wp-content/themes/adamos/images/facebook.png"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: one more thing: if you go on the [link](http://svycarsky-dum-responsive.geneweb.cz/)  webpage, you will see, that on the mobile size, the picture on the right does the same thing, footer did...do you know how to solve that? @hopkins-matt

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're talking about. Maybe take a screenshot.

Comment: [link](http://gyazo.com/1957851b106425bc603d66fd6a14e97c) that's it... @hopkins-matt

Comment: Change line 100 of your `style.css` file to this:

`a img {
 border: 0;
 max-width: 100%;
}`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in those lines

```
<div class="site-info">
<div style="max-width: 960px; margin: 0px auto; width: 100%;">
    <p style="float:left;">&copy; Copyright 2015 Hotel Švýcarský Dům</p>
    <div style="float:right;">Naleznete nás na sociálních sítích: 
        <a href="" style="display: block; float:right; margin:-4px 0 0 5px;"><img src="/wp-content/themes/adamos/images/gplus.png"></a>
        <a href="" style="display: block; float:right; margin:-4px 5px 0 5px;"><img src="/wp-content/themes/adamos/images/facebook.png"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

If you put this css script in the page, or in any css file your problem should be solved.

```
    <style>
@media(min-width:960px) {
    .site-info div {
        margin: 0 auto !important;
        max-width: 960px !important;
        width: 100% !important;
    }
    .site-info div div{width:auto !important;}
}
@media(max-width:960px) {
    .site-info div {
        margin: 0 2% !important;
        max-width: 960px !important;
        width: 96% !important;
    }
    .site-info div div{width:auto !important;}
}
@media(max-width:630px) {

    .site-info div {
        margin: 0 2% !important;
        max-width: 960px !important;
        text-align: center !important;
        width: 96% !important;
    }

    .site-info div div, .site-info p {
        clear: left !important;
        float: none !important;
    }
}
</style>
```

> @hopkins-matt answer might be correct, but if you want to get better results with other device width like Tablets use the above script.

Comment: Removing the inline width style will allow for that div's width to be controlled without the need to use `!important` to override it.

Comment: Yes, I added it just because I thought that css will be put inside css file and the inline style is generated through javascript.